# Назовите языки, где исходник может анализировать и модифицировать сам себя в COMPILE TIME

Tags: компиляция, парсер, метапрограммирование, самомодификация

### Чтобы исходник фактически содержал в себе текст своего же компилятора(парсера)

Народ не понимает. Объясню подробней.
Посоветуйте язык программирования сверхвысокого уровня (ЯПСВУ), программа на котором могла бы в COMPILE TIME обрабатывать и изменять свой же собственный код

Приведу простейший и надуманный пример для иллюстрации того, в чем же идея.

К примеру, чтобы язык,к примеру, поддерживал конструкции типа "если вызов метода Tarl::MySleep(int, double) присутствует в коде программы более 3-х раз - то определить тип MyType как long double".

Повторяю. Пример чисто вымышленный и искусственный, и служит чиста для иллюстрации идеи.

Вообщем нужен ЯПСВУ, который "искоропки" имел бы конструкции, которые позволяли бы писать программы, анализирующие и меняющие свой же собственный код во время компиляции (!!! Не в run-time). Т.е. чтобы программа являлась одновременно как бы пользовательским расширением компилятора и языка.

Соответственно, получается, что когда пишешь программу на таком языке, и меняешь ТЕКСТ какой-то её части, то ТЕКСТ других частей программы может при компиляции автоматом измениться {что есть такая штука как "препроцессор" я в курсе - но нужны более серьёзные и радикальные ВСТРОЕННЫЕ в язык средства. Препроцессорных средств (например #IFDEF и макросов с параметрами в языке C++) мне недостаточно. Нужно чтобы язык включал в себя более продвинутые средства парсинга и модификации своего же собственного исходника}.

Т.е. в ЯПСВУ должны быть операторы, операндами которых служат текстовые объекты в самом исходнике.

Почему я назвал такой язык языком СВЕРХ высокого уровня?

Ну потому что на нем пишут не исходник, а "исходник исходника" если можно так выразиться.

Т.е. чтобы исходник на языке представлял собой как бы смесь компилятора+прикладнухи, написанном на одном языке. Причем чтобы в исходнике "был растворен" не весь компилятор, а только его расширение для данной прикладной задачи.

Если совсем по простому, то нужен язык, у которого очень мощный препроцессор, не ограничивающийся имеющимися почти во всех языках банальными "IFDEF" и макросами с параметрами.
Чтобы язык был изначально заточен под описания парсинга исходника в самом же исходнике

Comment: возможно, Вам нужен https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemerle

Comment: Посмотрите на [макросы Haxe](http://haxe.org/manual/macro.html) и [применение их на практике](https://github.com/jasononeil/compiletime).

Comment: D позволяет при компиляции выполнять отдельные куски вашего кода, которые могут например из вашего domain specific language сформировать код на D (который будет скомпилирован).

Comment: Мне кажется, или автор вопроса имел в виду `class_eval` в Ruby. Считай код, который пишет сам себя в runtime. Вот пример: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb#L63 А ещё, согласно Википедии, Ruby является языком программирования свехвысокого уровня (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), как и HTML :D

Answer (score 3):

Язык TeX, например, умеет модифицировать исходный текст во время компиляции (он таким образом, например, собирает перекрёстные ссылки). Но при этом он не «содержит» своего парсера. Он просто умеет создавать (и пересоздавать) файлы во время компиляции, и динамически подключать их.

Comment: Нет. Это мне не подходит. Мне нужно, чтобы язык "искоробки" поддерживал конструкции, которые позволяли бы описывать прямо в исходнике фактически часть кода его же компилятора/парсера.

Comment: Препроцессорных средств (например #IFDEF и макросов с параметрами в языке C++) мне недостаточно. Нужно чтобы язык включал в себя более продвинутые средства парсинга и модификации своего же собственного исходника

Comment: @ИсмаилПрокопенко: Я не вполне понимаю смысл словосочетания «не подходит». Пример подходит под ваш _вопрос_, а то, что он вам не пригодился, это, вероятно, проблема формулировки самого вопроса. Мы же с вами не играем в игру «угадай то, не знаю что»?

Comment: А компилятор языка написан на самом языке практически всегда, следовательно, _любой_ язык из коробки содержит конструкции, позволяющие реализовать разбор и компиляцию языка.